# Delay in recv()

Tags: c, sockets, send, recv, ioctl

I have two programs that use socket programming to communicate. Initially I will specify the no. of hops as to how many time they have to exchange messages between each other. Each time it receives a message, it will append its id to it. Hence the string grows in size every time. My program is working fine for 8000 hops, but after it crosses 8000, although program p1 sends   a string of length 16388, p2 identifies that there are only 16385 in the socket ready to be read.  I use ioctl() to determine the amount of characters ready to recv() in the socket, and then recv it in a char * variable...

Is it because there is a delay in the send () in p1 and recv() in p2 , that p2 identifies only 16385 characters in the socket ?

For ex:
If P1 sends length(16388)

P2 receives only  the following  length(16385)

Comment: UDP, TCP or other socket?  Also, you use ioctl() to get characters available, is this how p2 is identifying only 16385 bytes?

Comment: @Jake: I use SOCK_STREAM for creating the socket. Although p1 send 16388 , ioctl() sees only 16385, is why i am confused.

Answer (score 6):

Say I'm trying to send you 8 pumpkins. I put 6 of them on the table. You think, "I'm expecting 8 pumpkins, not 6. I'll wait until he puts the last two on the table." I think, "I don't want too many pumpkins 'in flight' at once. I'll wait until he takes 2 of these 6 before I put the last 2 on the table." We're stuck. We're each waiting for the other. We'll wait forever.

You are not permitted to wait until more bytes are received before accepting the bytes that have already been received. The reason for this is simple: No network protocol can allow each side to wait for the other. Since TCP permits the sending side to wait in this context, it cannot permit the receiving side to wait as well.

So accept the bytes as they are received. Don't wait for the other side to send all of them before accepting any of them. Otherwise, what happens if the other side is waiting for you to accept the first one before it sends any more?

Comment: I use SOCK_STREAM, also I use ioctl to know before hand how many bytes are available to read. The problem now is that since ioctl() identifies less number of , in P2 I do not get the entire string sent by P1. What do you mean by "Don't wait for the other side to send all of them at once" ? I have a single recv() function aimed to receive all data sent by P1 at once>
If I run my program with VALGRIND, I don't get this behaviour. P2 is able to receive all that P1 is sending exactly and the program works correctly.

Comment: You can't assume that it's possible to receive all the data at once. The sender is permitted to refuse to send the last part until you accept the first part. Thus you cannot be permitted to refuse to accept the first part until he sends the last part. Yes, sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't. If you follow the rules, it will work every time.

Comment: So do you suggest that I do a recv() till I reach the end of the message, which has say a '\0' termination ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You cannot wait until the whole message is received. You must accept it as it comes on or you will slow/stall the transmitter.

Comment: With TCP you can't assume the number of read/write calls will equal the number of messages. This is what a SOCK_STREAM socket is. It wouldn't be a bug for read and write to only handle 1 byte at a time, just horribly slow. In real life tcp reads/write are generally limited to a few kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting a kernel buffer limit. You can probably increase SO_RCVBUF on the receiver and it will work as you expect: SIOCINQ will eventually return the full size of the unread data.

But you shouldn't do that to ensure proper Functioning. messing with buffers should only be done when you want to tweak performance.

You should restructure the code so that you never have to ask the kernel how many bytes are available. Just read up to a reasonable limit(like 4096) and deal with one application-level message being broken up in multiple pieces. If you need message lengths/boundaries then you MUST implement them yourself on top of TCP.

Here's some silly code to read a message with a length header:

```
int ret, len = 0, have_read;
have_read = 0;
while (have_read < sizeof(len)) {
    // This will likely always return sizeof(len) the first time.
    ret = read(fd, ((char*)&len) + have_read, sizeof(len) - have_read);
    if (ret <= 0) {
        // Handle error.
    }
    have_read += ret;
}
char* buf = malloc(len);
if (!buf) {
    // Handle error.
}
have_read = 0;
while (have_read < len) {
    ret = read(fd, buf + have_read, len - have_read);
    if (ret <= 0) {
        // Handle error.
    }
    have_read += ret;
}
// Handle message in buf.
```

Comment: I need to ask how many bytes are available, so that I can do a malloc() correspondingly for receiving the data in to a buffer in recv().
So my aim was to know before hand, how much data is sent by p1 by reading the buffer using ioctl() and then doing a malloc() for a variable to receive the data into it. 
However since the wrong size is returned I do have problems in the logic of my code.

Comment: @ManojKumar - The size is not wrong, it's just less that what you wrote. That ioctl how many bytes are immediately available in the tcp buffer, which is limited. If you read all of the reported data more will show up. If you need to malloc the entire size of your message then write the length in a separate header and fill the buffer with multiple read calls. You should consider processing data on the fly without any mallocs.

Comment: But If i separate messages and length in two different send() from P1, the messages sometime gets clubbed together. P2 sees them as a single message and the P2 starts to wait in next recv() indefinately.  Hence I had to pack both length and message into a single entity. So my ioctl, doesn't see the entire data. How can i know about the size of data I will get in recv() or how can I get the entire data in p2 in recv() ?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Forget the `ioctl`. Allocate a reasonable-sized buffer, say 16KB. Always try to receive 16KB. Then look at what you got and figure out what it means. You are trying to teach TCP your protocol. Let TCP give you whatever it has, and *you* implement the protocol.

Comment: What if my incoming data size becomes larger than 16kb ? I want to allocate buffer based on my incoming data. Also now I am able to make mutiple recv() calls till i get all data. But a new problem has propped up, If P1 sends data of length 20000, P2 receives the first 16384 and in the next recv() call it receives the remaining message and appends its to the former one. But in some cases, the second recv(), is not able to get the remaining data. So what it loses a part of the original message.

Comment: Also the ioctl() gets executed before the buffer is filled up with remaining data, say in case of 20000. Initially 16384 is filled up and the before the remaining data is filled out in the buffer, ioctl is executed and it return 0.